# Powershell - Variable not expanding

Tags: powershell

The variable `$cygwin_folder` can be different in some servers. But for some reason it is not expanding. Maybe its due to slash `c:\$cygwin_folder` but I'm not sure how to fix this?

```
c:\$cygwin_folder\bin\bash.exe -c some_command
```

Here is the code:

```
if(test-path("c:\cygwin")) {
$cygwin_folder = "cygwin";
}
ElseIF (test-path("c:\cygwin64")) {
$cygwin_folder = "cygwin64";
}
Else {
echo "Cygwin directory not found";
exit
}

c:\$cygwin_folder\bin\bash.exe -c some_command
```

Error:

```
c:\$cygwin_folder\bin\bash.exe : The term 'c:\$cygwin_folder\bin\bash.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path 
is correct and try again.
At C:\Program Files\zabbix\userparams\myscript.ps1:79 char:1
+ c:\$cygwin_folder\bin\bash.exe -c ("/usr/bin/scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c:\$cygwin_folder\bin\bash.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implicit string expansion only works for parameter arguments, use the `&` call operator to invoke an expandable string as a command instead:

```
& "c:\$cygwin_folder\bin\bash.exe" -c some_command
```